# SqlDataReader filling combobox IsDBNull issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

Hello I have tried to handle Null exception but I'm still receiving the exception warning: data is null this method or property cannot be called on null values.

This is my code:

```
 spojeni.Open();
        string sql_combobox = "SELECT column FROM tableO RDER BY nazev ASC";
        SqlCommand combobox = new SqlCommand(sql_combobox, spojeni);


        try
        {
            SqlDataReader dr = combobox.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["column"]);
                }
            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
            spojeni.Close();
        }
```

Comment: In the check, you're checking column #0, but in the `Add` call you're getting the column by name.  I would venture to guess the column you are requesting is not actually column #0.

Comment: No, the `Select query` has only `1` column, that means `0` is the same to `column`.

Comment: which line is giving you error?if (!dr.IsDBNull(0)) or comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["column"]); ?

Comment: @NoOne and Everyone else, Sorry for this it was error on another method I haven't mentioned that. Sorry once again.

Comment: @Marek what's that method? You mean your problem has been solved?

Comment: @KingKing Sorry I meant method like this method() I already solved it. I was calling another SqlCommand where wasn't DbNull handled. Thanks again.

Comment: `string sql_combobox = "SELECT column FROM tableO RDER BY nazev ASC";`  This code scares me because it is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection).  Please do some research on [parameterized queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i get from your code

```
spojeni.Open();
//change your query string there was an error in it
string sql_combobox = "SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY nazev ASC";
SqlCommand combobox = new SqlCommand(sql_combobox, spojeni);


try
{
   SqlDataReader dr = combobox.ExecuteReader();
   while (dr.Read())
   {
       if (!dr.IsDBNull(0))
       {
          comboBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
       }
   }

   dr.Close();
   dr.Dispose();
   spojeni.Close();
}
```

Comment: If so, I guess the exception would be `SQLException` (syntax error) right at `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: @KingKing you are right. That is why i wanted to know the line that is giving the error.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify the column you are checking for ...  try something like this:

```
if (dr["column"] != DBNull.Value)
{
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["column"]);
}
```

Comment: This would be perfect if you explain why `IsDBNull` doesn't work?